# In Gradle, why is `targetCompatibility` compiler option being ignored? How to disable compatibility check completely?

Tags: java, scala, gradle, gradle-kotlin-dsl

I'm trying to use splain plugin 1.0.2 for Scala 2.13.11. According to its build definition file, it is published to be compatible with any Java version higher than 1.8:

https://github.com/tek/splain/blob/Release/1.0.2-2.13.11/build.gradle.kts#L1

```
    tasks {
        val jvmTarget = JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8.toString()

        withType<ScalaCompile> {

            targetCompatibility = jvmTarget
```

Unfortunantely, when being imported as a Scala compiler plugin:

```
            val splainD = "io.tryp:splain_2.13.11:1.0.2"

            scalaCompilerPlugins(splainD)
```

I got the following error:

```
Execution failed for task ':prover-commons:core:compileTestFixturesScala'.
> Could not resolve all files for configuration ':prover-commons:core:testFixturesCompileClasspath'.
   > Could not resolve io.tryp:splain_2.13.11:1.0.2.
     Required by:
         project :prover-commons:core
      > No matching variant of io.tryp:splain_2.13.11:1.0.2 was found. The consumer was configured to find a library for use during compile-time, compatible with Java 8, preferably in the form of class files, preferably optimized for standard JVMs, and its dependencies declared externally but:
          - Variant 'apiElements' capability io.tryp:splain_2.13.11:1.0.2 declares a library for use during compile-time, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'javadocElements' capability io.tryp:splain_2.13.11:1.0.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)
          - Variant 'runtimeElements' capability io.tryp:splain_2.13.11:1.0.2 declares a library for use during runtime, packaged as a jar, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares a component, compatible with Java 11 and the consumer needed a component, compatible with Java 8
              - Other compatible attribute:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
          - Variant 'sourcesElements' capability io.tryp:splain_2.13.11:1.0.2 declares a component for use during runtime, and its dependencies declared externally:
              - Incompatible because this component declares documentation and the consumer needed a library
              - Other compatible attributes:
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java environment (preferred optimized for standard JVMs)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its target Java version (required compatibility with Java 8)
                  - Doesn't say anything about its elements (required them preferably in the form of class files)
```

(This error can be observed on CI: https://github.com/tribbloid/prover-commons/actions/runs/5773185275/job/15648874150)

(all Gradle snippets are written in kotlin scripts)

So my questions are:

- Why is splain 1.0.2 reported to be only compatible with Java 11, despite being explicitly told to use another Java version?
- How to temporarily disable this check from consumer side?

Comment: Are you running gradle itself on Java 8?

Comment: @daniu yes. I won't know which Java version was used to publish splain to Gradle online repository tho